# Related to Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

How obvious it is to have $$a^p\equiv a \pmod p$$ where 
$a$  is an integer and  $p$ is a prime.

Can you feel it true? May you please explain it to me in very simple words that how $a^p$ and $a$ leaves the same remainder when divided by $p$.

Comment: Have you seen the proof?

Comment: Personally: it's not at all an obvious fact at a glance, which is probably why it is so remarkable. That's not to say it isn't justified - there's a number of proofs on it. which you can see at Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem). Mathologer on YouTube also offers an explanation of one of the more "visual" proofs (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9fbBSxhkuA)

Comment: Thank you Sir for your very positive reply. I will try to understand those proofs.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you Sir for your help. I will keep it in my mind, writing questions next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all obvious. Quite likely, Fermat observed the fact for all “small” primes and so tried to see whether it holds for *every* prime.

It's not the same as other proofs with “infinite descent”, because it's not possible to reduce to a smaller prime, or, at least, I can't see how it could be done.

By the binomial theorem,
$$
(b+1)^p=\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}b^k
$$
Since $p\mid\binom{p}{k}$ for $0<k<p$, we can see that
$$
p\mid\bigl((b+1)^p-(b+1)\bigr)
$$
Set $b+1=a$ and you're done.

The [binomial theorem had been known for several decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#History) when Fermat did his work. Note however that there is no known proof by Fermat himself; the first proof was published by [Euler in 1749](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html).

Comment: Thank you Sir, I really wanted this type of insight only that what could have there in Fermat's mind, what was his thought process, if anyone can think about that (as we actually can't know.)

Answer (score 1):

When a and p are coprime, note that $a, 2a, 3a,....... (p-1)a$ all leave different remainders when divided by $p\in [1, p-1]$. Multiply all the congruences and eliminate $(p-1)!$ from the resulting congruence as gcd$[(p-1)!, p] = 1$. You get the desired result by multiplying $a$ on both sides afterward